# Android Activity is recreated when activity from background(pause) to foreground

Tags: android, android-activity, recreate

Hi Android professionals,

I fell into a small issue about some activity life cycle. I mentioned my problem with step by step:-

1. launch the app with app icon from home screen.
2. Enter some data into a edit text fields in recyclerview in activity **A**.
3. press the home button and launch the other app(any app like facebook ,twitter).
4. now our app is in paused state and in background with empty values.
5. now click the recent apps button and launch our application (from background).
6. now the app is launched with Activity **A** but that activity is recreated .

I was also disable Don't keep activities in Developer options.My Testing tab is Levono A8 50.

I wasted 3 days time on this issue. Any one have any ideas on this issue.
thanks

Comment: This problem is Memory Specific Have you checked on Other Devices ?

Comment: I was tested in  lenovo a3300-gv kitkat version, working fine . but not working in  Levono A8 50 lollipop verions. any chance to optimized memory specs

Comment: Thats the Android's behavior .OS will destroy the activity(Which is not in forground) if in need of more resources. In other way this can be treated as a feature for Bettery and Resource Optimization.

Comment: hi ADM, Can we control this behaviour.

Comment: As i said its OS dependent you can not control it . What you can do is save the state of Activity during stop.

Answer (score 0):

Not a problem but feature - Your activity can be killed and recreated  after losing focus as Android OS wishes  -  get used to it. Your activity shall save all necessary state in onPause()

Comment: Hi  konstantin, the activity  have recyclerview with so many rows with checkboxes and edittext fields. it is very hard to saved. Is there any idea .

Comment: You can use some databinding library (I already developed one: https://github.com/ko5tik/andject )  And here how it is used to read / write preferences:   https://github.com/ko5tik/accanalyser/blob/master/src/de/pribluda/android/accanalyzer/Configuration.java

Answer (score 0):

As soon as your current activity is not visible anymore after launching another app, it is in a stopped state. You can't however count on the activity remaining in that state. Android will destroy the activity if in need of more resources (and then recreate it later on). If you want data to persist, you need to store them using SharedPreferences or a database in onSaveInstanceState().

Check [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#saras) for more info on the matter.

Comment: Hi kazume, the activity have recyclerview with so many rows with checkboxes and edittext fields. it is very hard to saved. Is there any idea

Comment: What is the data source for that RecyclerView (or for the adapter). I'd suggest moving that to a ViewModel (from architecture components) tied to the activity's lifecycle.

Comment: Hi kazume , We have used viewmodel for data binding to recyclerview. But i have no idea , how to save and display user entered data in recyclerview.